# 現在、「開いているタブボタン」を押した際に、設定しているWebViewの再読込（Top画面）を読み込むにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

Tags: android, android-fragments

現在、「開いているタブボタン」を押した際に、設定しているWebViewの再読込（Top画面）を読み込むにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

詳細：
　お世話なっております。
　今回、自分のコードではないので文章で説明させていただきます。　
　現在、4タブ画面（FragmentTabHostを使用）にWebViewを設定。
　各画面ごとに最初にHPのTOP画面を表示されており、HP内の内容が読めるようにしています。
　例えるなら、各タブにニュースサイトが4つ当てはめらており、内部の記事が読めるようになっております。
　ご相談したいのは、すでに「開いているタブボタン」を押した際に「そのタブのTop画面」を表示させる（再読込？）する方法についてです。

TabFragment.javaのonActivityCreatedに以下のコードを追加し、タブ０を押した際にイベントを拾うところまでできたのですが、再読込する方法を模索している状況です。
　自分はまだ、Androidの勉強を初めて一年ちょっとの素人です。
　このところ理解不足から「思い込み」で時間を潰すことが多いことからご相談させていただきました。
　アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChidTabViewAt(0).setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()){
//@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Log.e("mTabHost.getTabWidget()","タブ０が押された")
}
});
```

補足させていただきます。
ただ、上で記載した通り自分のコードではないのでぼかした感じでご容赦ください。

onActivityCreatedに

```
mTabHost =(FragmentTabHost)this.〜（〜.tabhost）;
mTabHost.setup(This.〜,this〜)

for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(〜).〜fragments[i],null);
}
mTabHost.setCurentTab(0);
```

動作ができるようになったのでコードを記載します。
tab0の表示のときのみsetCurrentTab(1)→setCurrentTab(0)
tab1〜３はsetCurrentTab(0)→setCurrentTab(各タブ（１，２，３）)で
無理やり動作させているのですが、目的の動作が可能となりました。
ありがとうございました。

```
//tab0　再クリック時に表示画面を戻す
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("mTabHost.getTabWidget()", "tab0　クリック");
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);//一度、tab1を表示させ（なんちゃって初期化？）すぐに下を表示させる)
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);//これでtab0が表示される
        }
    });
    //tab1　再クリック時に表示画面を戻す
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("mTabHost.getTabWidget()", "tab1　クリック");
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);//一度、tab0を表示させ（なんちゃって初期化？）すぐに下を表示させる)
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);//これでtab1が表示される
        }
        });
```

Comment: TabHostに子供のFragmentを追加する部分のコードって載せていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: fkm様、お世話になっております。
ご指摘された部分を補足させていただきました。
アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FragmentTabHost`のJavadocにも有用な情報がなかったのでソースも見てみました。

`mTabHost.setup()`で、引数3つ版の第3引数で、実際にどのコンテナIDにFragmentを貼るかを指定できます。なので、現在表示中の`Fragment`を取得するには、`setup()`の第2引数で渡したのと同じ`FragmentManager`に対して`findFragmentById()`を呼ぶことで、現在表示中の`Fragment`が取得できると思います。

Comment: fkm様、お世話になっております。
ご回答を元に何とか動くものができました。
ありがとうございます。
現在は、質問に追加した項目を勉強です。
アドバイスを頂けるようならよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: １質問１回答にしたほうが、あとから検索で訪れた方が助かると思うので、別の質問として再度出しませんか？（回答はぱっと浮かんだのですぐやります）

Comment: 失礼いたしました。
別問題として質問させていただきます。
ご迷惑をおかけしました。

Comment: 別問題「TabHostのsetOnClickListenerの表記の仕方を教えて下さい。」を提出させていただきました。
よろしければ、アドバイスをお願いいたします。